# How to copy cell content from one workbook to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the content of a specific cell from one workbook(MRP) to the other(Schedule Template 2). Both have different addresses and it should only copy it when it finds the word Schedule in a different column.

I have tried the following code

**Module 1:**

```
Sub BAUMER1()

    Dim x As String

    'Activate Worksheet'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MRP").Activate
    'Select first line of date'
    Worksheets("MRP").Range("Z3").Select

    'Set search variable'
    x = "BAUMER 1"

    'Set Do loop to stop at empty cell'
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        'Check active cell for search value.'
        If ActiveCell.Value = x Then
            Call FindSchedule("BAUMER.(1)")
            Exit Do
        End If
        'Step down 1 row from present location.'
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub

Sub LIBERTY1()

    Dim x As String
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MRP").Activate
    'Select first line of date'
    Worksheets("MRP").Range("Z3").Select

    'Set search variable'
    x = "LIBERTY 1"

    'Set Do loop to stop at empty cell'
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
      'Check active cell for search value.'
      If ActiveCell.Value = x Then
          Call FindSchedule("LIBERTY.(1)")
          Exit Do
      End If
      'Step down 1 row from present location.'
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

**Module 2:**

```
Sub FindSchedule(machine As String)

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Dim x As String
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim countX As Integer
    Dim machine2 As String
    machine2 = machine

    countX = 6
    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("MRP 6-13-2019.xlsm").Worksheets("MRP")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Schedule Template 2.xlsm").Worksheets(machine2)

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MRP").Activate
    ' Select first line of data.
    Worksheets("MRP").Range("G2").Select
    ' Set search variable value.
     x = "Schedule"
    'Set Do loop to stop at empty cell'
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
      'Check active cell for search value.'
      If ActiveCell.Value = x Then
          a = ActiveCell.Row
          Exit Do

      End If
      wsCopy.Cells("a,1").Copy
      wsDest.Cells("countX,5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      countX = countX + 1
      'Step down 1 row from present location.'
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

I need to copy the contents of a cell from wsCopy(MRP) at position row of active cell and first column to a cell i wsDest(Schedule Template 2) at position of counterX that begins at 6 and increments.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to [avoid using activate and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code.

Comment: Do you know how I can specify which one I am referring to without using those keywords? @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: The answers to the question I linked to offer different ways to do it. I suggest assigning the objects (workbooks, sheets, etc.) to variables.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thank you for the helpful link! I assigned them to variables. It is still not pasting to the other worksheet :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a template that I use for just about everything, it also allows you to select multiple files if need be, and loops through each file you selected.

```
Private Sub Import()

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim FileChosen As Integer
    Dim tempWB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    fd.InitialFileName = "C:\"  #'Change this area to whatever folder you want
    fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

    FileChosen = fd.Show
    If FileChosen = -1 Then

        For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count

            Set tempWB = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(i))

            #'Copy over your data here

            tempWB.Close False
            Set tempWB = Nothing

        Next i

    Else:
        Exit Sub

    End If

End Sub
```